# Searcher Gem and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, activerecord, rubygems

If I use in my Gemfile:

```
gem "searcher", github: "radar/searcher"
```

the bundle install works perfectly. but I'm trying to deploy for heroku and I'm getting this erros:

```
$ git push heroku master
    Counting objects: 1277, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (1218/1218), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (1277/1277), 143.11 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 1277 (delta 793), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected
    remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.6
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
    remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
    remote:        The git source `git://github.com/radar/searcher.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
    remote:        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
    remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
    remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
    remote:        You have added to the Gemfile:
    remote:        * source: git://github.com/radar/searcher.git (at master)
    remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
    remote:        * source: https://github.com/radar/searcher.git (at master@c297512)
    remote:        Bundler Output: The git source `git://github.com/radar/searcher.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
    remote:        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
    remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
    remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
    remote:
    remote:        You have added to the Gemfile:
    remote:        * source: git://github.com/radar/searcher.git (at master)
    remote:
    remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
    remote:        * source: https://github.com/radar/searcher.git (at master@c297512)
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !   Push rejected to glacial-beyond-39560.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/glacial-beyond-39560.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/glacial-beyond-39560.git'
```

Then I try to tweak in the Gemfile to put just the `gem "searcher"` and I have an error when try to bundle:

```
   Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activerecord (= 4.2.1)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.1) was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.2.1)

    searcher was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 3.0.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I saw it's recommended to use ActiveRecord 3x. What I need to do(install a version of rails for active_record 3x? Or I thick is something with secure protocol for this gem?? Can anyone help me please???

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot ways I have successful changing:

```
gem "searcher", github: "radar/searcher"
```

for this:

```
gem "searcher", git: "https://github.com/radar/searcher.git"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think Delete the contents of Gemfile.lock, and run bundle install again. That's been working for me.

Comment: I try to do this a lot of times and nothing,I think  it's something with security SSH in production mode or the version of the active record. Wich version of rails I need to install for use the activerecord 3x??? I have already installed the version of active record 3.2.22.5. Thank's Sunny!